# FirebaseFirestoreSwift installed through SwiftPackageManager does not support Codable

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, codable, swift-package-manager

I am having troubles with decoding a custom object type from Firestore. Essentialy, it is a nested data model, a collection which contains another sub-collection. My swift struct model conforms to `Codable` as it is shown in firebase documentation here: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/9f9d60e29a2e4ebd827de74af419ab55eef09451/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/ViewController.swift#L755-L788
im able to access document in collection, however this example uses throwable method called `data(as: )` (it accepts generic type which conforms to codable) which for some reason i cannot see in xcode autocompletion. I want to use this specific method to avoid serialization through dictionaries.
Im using Swift package Manager and i have already imported all necessary frameworks: Firestore and FirestoreSwiftBeta. i have also tried to resolve packages but it gives no effect. The only assumption i have is that this `data(as:)` method is only supported in SwiftUI projects, however my project is plain UIKit.
My firebase package version is `8.5.0`

Comment: Does the source have `import FirebaseFirestoreSwift`?

Comment: It does have import line with this module. And there is no error such: module is not found.

Comment: Example usage at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/firestore/FirestoreExample/RestaurantsTableViewController.swift#L79

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t quite get, how can it help me. My issue is that there is simply no such method as data(as: ), even though FirebaseFirestoreSwift is imported into the source.

Comment: You could binary search the difference between that working example and your not-working example

Comment: You cannot use `data(as:)` on a collection. It must be on a Firestore document. Check your code and see if you are calling `data(as:)` on a collection or document.

Comment: Yep, I’m calling it on a document. Double checked that already, but thanks for notice!

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I found out what was causing the issue. It was the Firebase iOS latest version (8.5.0). After downgrading through SPM to 8.4.0 autocompletion and and methods from FirebaseFirestoreSwift has appeared.